# C# Lambda Join with Multiple Conditions in a SQL Left Outer Join

Tags: c#, lambda, left-join

I have the following SQL:

```
 select * 
  from  [dbo].[CustomField] cf
  left outer join [dbo].[CustomFieldDataItem] cd on cd.CustomFieldId = cf.Id and cd.OutsideId = 180
  where cf.AnotherId = 1
```

And I want to write it in C# Lambda BUT my code only shows the data items for custom fields that have data items - I want to see all the custom fields and whether they have data items - so far I have got this:

```
var myQuery = _db.CustomFields
                        .Where(c => c.AnotherId == 1)
                        .Join(_db.CustomFieldDataItems, cf => cf.Id, cd => cd.CustomFieldId, (cf, cd) => new { cf, cd })
                        .Where(f => f.cd.OutsideId == 180)
                        .Select(z => new CustomFieldModel
                        {
                            CustomFieldId = z.cf.Id,
                            Name = z.cf.Name,
                            DataValue = z.cd.DataValue
                        }).ToList()
```

I don't know where to place the OutsideId where clause which really should be a part of the join

Comment: The entity CustomFields have a navigation property aganist the entity CustomFieldDataItems?

Comment: Yes CustomFieldId

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In response to all @Cetin Basoz workings I was able to get a solution using LinqPad in Lambda - instead of Join I needed to use SelecctMany() in this example:

```
var myQuery = _db.CustomFields.SelectMany(
                      cf => cf.DataItems.Where(d => d.OutsideId == x.Id).DefaultIfEmpty(),
                      (cf, cd) => new {cf, cd })
                   .Where(s => s.cf.AnotherId == 1)
                   .Select(
                      m =>
                         new MyModel
                         {
                             CustomFieldId = m.cf.Id,
                             Name = m.cf.Name,
                             DataType = m.cf.DataType,
                             StringValue = m.cd.StringValue,
                             IntValue = m.cd.IntValue,
                             BoolValue = m.cd.BoolValue,
                             DateTimeValue = m.cd.DateTimeValue,
                             DecimalValue = m.cd.DecimalValue
                         }
                   ).ToList()
```

Comment: That doesn't look right to me. Check the lambda version that I added at the end of my message. With a 'left join', writing like this without nullables is likely to error out.

Answer (score 2):

In Linq you really need join very rarely:

```
var myQuery = _db.CustomFields
                 .Where(c => c.AnotherId == 1)
                 .Select(cf => new CustomFieldModel
                 {
                     CustomFieldId = cf.Id,
                     Name = cf.Name,
                     DataValue = cf.cd.Any(cd => cd.OutSideId == 180) 
                              ? cf.cd.First(cd => cd.OutSideId == 180).DataValue
                              : (<type?>)null;
                 }).ToList();
```

In LinqToSQL this would generate an SQL like:

```
DECLARE @p0 int = 1;
DECLARE @p1 Int = 180;
DECLARE @p2 Int = 180;

SELECT [t0].[CustomFieldId], [t0].[Name], 
    (CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
            FROM [CustomFieldDataItems] AS [t1]
            WHERE ([t1].[OutsideID] = @p1) AND ([t1].[CustomFieldID] = [t0].[ID])
            ) THEN (
            SELECT [t3].[DataValue]
            FROM (
                SELECT TOP (1) [t2].[DataValue]
                FROM [CustomFieldDataItems] AS [t2]
                WHERE ([t2].[OutsideID] = @p2) AND ([t2].[CustomFieldID] = [t0].[ID])
                ) AS [t3]
            )
        ELSE NULL
     END) AS [DataValue]
FROM [CustomFields] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[AnotherId] = @p0
```

That actually doesn't produce the result with your original SQL (I used First to get the DataValue which would mean you wouldn't get result as 1-Many).

Then we could rewrite it with as in this optimized version which also produces the result you have originally (not sure if you want rows from CustomFields be repeated - your SQL does):

```
var myQuery = (from cf in CustomFields
              from cd in cf.CustomFieldDataItems.Where(d => d.OutsideId==180).DefaultIfEmpty()
              where cf.AnotherId == 1
              select new CustomFieldModel
             {
                 CustomFieldId = cf.Id,
                 Name = cf.Name,
                 DataValue = cd == null?(int?)null:cd.DataValue,
                 AnotherValue = cd == null?(<typeName?>)null:cd.AnotherValue,
             }).ToList();
```

Generated SQL would look like:

```
DECLARE @p0 Int = 1;
DECLARE @p1 Int = 180;

SELECT [t0].[CustomFieldId], [t0].[Name], 
    (CASE 
        WHEN [t2].[test] IS NULL THEN NULL
        ELSE [t2].[DataValue]
     END) AS [DataValue], 
    (CASE 
        WHEN [t2].[test] IS NULL THEN NULL
        ELSE [t2].[AnotherValue]
     END) AS [AnotherValue]
FROM [CustomFields] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS [test], [t1].[DataValue], [t1].[CustomFieldID], [t1].[AnotherValue], [t1].[OutsideId]
    FROM [CustomFieldDataItems] AS [t1]
    ) AS [t2] ON ([t2].[OutsideId] = @p0) AND ([t2].[CustomFieldID] = [t0].[ID])
WHERE [t0].[AnotherId] = @p1;
```

EDIT: Further thinking about that, it could be more simplified to:

```
var myQuery = (from cf in CustomFields
              from cd in cf.CustomFieldDataItems.Where(d => d.OutsideId==180).DefaultIfEmpty()
              where cf.AnotherId == 1
              select new CustomFieldModel
             {
                 CustomFieldId = cf.Id,
                 Name = cf.Name,
                 DataValue = (int?)cd.DataValue,
                 AnotherValue = (<typeName?>)cd.AnotherValue,
             }).ToList();
```

That would generate SQL like:

```
DECLARE @p0 Int = 180;
DECLARE @p1 Int = 1;

SELECT [t0].[CustomFieldId], [t0].[Name], 
       [t1].[DataValue], [t1].[AnotherValue]
FROM [CustomFields] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [CustomFieldDataItems] AS [t1] 
  ON ([t1].[OutSideId] = @p0) AND ([t1].[CustomFieldID] = [t0].[ID])
WHERE [t0].[AnotherId] = @p1;
```

Almost same as your original one.

Just for completing as "lambda":

```
var myQuery = _db.CustomFields
   .Where (cf => cf.AnotherId == 1)
   .SelectMany (
      cf => cf.CustomFieldDataItems.Where (cd => (cd.OutsideId == (Int32?)180)).DefaultIfEmpty(), 
      (cf, cd) => new CustomFieldModel
             {
                 CustomFieldId = cf.Id,
                 Name = cf.Name,
                 DataValue = (int?)cd.DataValue,
                 AnotherValue = (<typeName?>)cd.AnotherValue,
             }
   ).ToList();
```

Comment: This query is apart of a much larger query - and I am returning more columns than just data value from the data items - so I would be if I followed your suggestion - querying the data items table many times per row. Efficiency is important here - which is why I need the lambda join

Comment: @MrRich, that is not true. While this is not 1-to-1 match to your query, it is similar and could be optimized. I will edit my answer to add some explanation and optimization.

Comment: @MrRich, I hope "lambda" is not a must, else you can use SelectMany to achieve it but not worth it IMHO.

Comment: I do need lambda and SelectMany did solve it - because of your LINQ example I was able to translate it using LINQPAD - and it auto-translated it using the select many

Comment: @MrRich, I don't understand why you "do need" lambda but anyway this would translate as SelectMany to lambda :) BTW, I utilize LinqPad to get generated SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This query was a small part of a much larger query using Lambda IQueryable - I didn't want to have to rewrite the entire query just to resolve this bit. Thanks again!

Comment: @MrRich, OK. Just for completeness added the lambda version too.

Answer (score 0):

try with `.DefaultIfEmpty()`

```
var myQuery = _db.CustomFields                   
    .Where(c => c.AnotherId == 1)
    .Join(_db.CustomFieldDataItems.DefaultIfEmpty(), cf => cf.Id, cd => cd.CustomFieldId, (cf, cd) => new { cf, cd })
    .Where(f => f.cd.OutsideId == 180)
    .Select(z => new CustomFieldModel
    {
        CustomFieldId = z.cf.Id,
        Name = z.cf.Name,
        DataValue = z.cd.DataValue
    }).ToList()
```

Comment: This didn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

If you have navigation property you can go like this:

```
var myQuery = _db.CustomFields.Include(x => x.CustomFieldDataItems && x.CustomFieldDataItems.OutsideId == 180)
.Where(c => c.AnotherId == 1).Select(z => new CustomFieldModel
                        {
                            CustomFieldId = z.Id,
                            Name = z.Name,
                            DataValue = z.CustomFieldDataItems.DataValue
                        }).ToList()
```

The "Include" is a "LEFT OUTER JOIN" on database t

EDIT: Changed include lambda

Comment: No that doesn't work because the outsideid = 180 filters out the rows that have no data items. I need to replicate the SQL which has 2 conditions in the join